# why mciSendString() to get status position fails in my code?

Tags: mci

Is there any way to query mci device to query current playing position so that we can resume from there to play later on ?

cmd.Format(L"status %d waveaudio position",m_iDeviceIDPlayer);

mcirez = mciSendString(cmd,buff.GetBuffer(),1024, NULL);

it gives this error : "The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI "

Is there any problem with command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MCI_STATUS_PARMS status;
status.dwItem = MCI_STATUS_POSITION;
status.dwCallback = 0;

dwReturn = mciSendCommand(m_iDeviceIDPlayer,MCI_STATUS,MCI_STATUS_ITEM|MCI_WAIT,(DWORD_PTR)&status);
```

Position -> status.dwReturn is the required position.