# Play music in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, audio

I have some problem with playing mp3 file in c++(I apologize for my english, it isn't my first language). I use winapi in programm for playing music(I am using function mciSendStringW). My programm will be using 3 thread. Main thread, thread for input/output operation and one for playing music. I have two problem:

1. I don't know, when music will be over(I don't know the song's size and length). I can use:

`mciSendStringW(LR"(play SongPath1.mp3 wait)", NULL, 0, NULL)`

But I have second problem

2. I can't stop music, if I use:

`mciSendStringW(LR"(play SongPath1.mp3 wait)", NULL, 0, NULL);`

Because, programm will be stop in this line, untill song will be over. Example, user switch off music, but, i can't say tread stop music and i can't kill music-thread in another thread. But if I use

```
mciSendStringW(LR"(play SongPath1.mp3)", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Whithout flag "wait" I can write something like that:

```
mciSendStringW(LR"(play SongPath1.mp3 )", NULL, 0, NULL);
while(true){
    g_song_mutex.lock();     /*global mutex for g_switch_off_music*/
    if(g_switch_off_music) { /*global bool for switch off music*/
        mciSendStringW(LR"(stop SongPath1.mp3)", NULL, 0, NULL);
        return;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(300));
    }
    g_song_mutex.unlock();
}
```

But I have more than one song and when first song is over, will be start secong. But i don't know, when song is over. And programm if I use:

```
 mciSendStringW(LR"(play SongPath1.mp3)", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Can't play second song(or repeat first), or if I use:

`mciSendStringW(LR"(play SongPath1.mp3 wait)", NULL, 0, NULL);`

Programm can't switch off song.

Comment: [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207961/why-mcisendstring-to-get-status-position-fails-in-my-code)

Comment: I looked, but it for save position in one song(or other media).

Comment: You should probably use wasapi instead, run a real audio thread.

Comment: What about using the [Notify flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Multimedia/the-notify-flag)

Comment: Can you explain, what you mean, when say "real audio thread". Link to guide or tutorial will be good.

Comment: paddy, I read about it, but I can't understand how use it.

Comment: You need a message loop to handle [`MM_MCINOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Multimedia/mm-mcinotify) message.

Comment: zett42, It is really can help me in this task. Can you write some example(or give link to guide or example). It is really will be good, because code better, than docs.

Comment: @emik_g You can reference [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14709/Playing-MP3s-using-MCI) code sample.